# Convert a arbitrarily nested list of literals to string representation

Tags: python, string, serialization

How can I convert a arbitrarily nested list of literals (string/numbers) to its string representation? 
For example,

```
nested_list = [[1,2,4],[1, [1, 2], [1]],2]
nested_list_string = "[[1,2,4],[1, [1, 2], [1]],2]"
```

Furthermore , it could be multilines:

```
[
    1, 2,
    [2,4]
]
```

can produces the string representation of equivalent single-line list i.e `"[1,2, [2,4]]"` or any other equivalent form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this with [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

```
str(nested_list)
```